# Ansible Fails to reload sysctl

Tags: ansible, sysctl

I am trying to add the following via ansible

```
---
  - name: Set sysctl for all.accept_ra=0
    sysctl:
      name: net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra
      value: 0
      state: present
```

and it keeps on giving me error:

```
TASK [ami : Set sysctl for all.accept_ra=0] ***************************************************************************************************
Friday 27 July 2018  17:35:20 +0530 (0:00:12.267)       0:00:12.327 *********** 
fatal: [172.16.14.152]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Failed to reload sysctl: sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/accept_ra: No such file or directory\n"}
```

I have tried quite some variants like

```
---
  - name: Set sysctl for all.accept_ra=0
    sysctl:
      name: net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra
      value: 0
      sysctl_set: yes
      state: present
      sysctl_file: /etc/sysctl.conf
      reload: yes
```

But the error persists, i am not sure why this keeps going to the path `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/accept_ra`

Any help ?

Comment: are you sure you're performing the action as root user ?

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear. For some reason the file does not exist. Is IPv6 enabled?

```
cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/accept_ra: No such file or directory
```

Comment: IPV6 is disabled